# Error occurring using guard in rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

Hey guys I'm following the rails tutorial found here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/the-intro-to-rails-screencast-i-wish-i-had/ and I've gotten to the point where you use guard to execute unit tests. I keep getting the error found below when using guard, I tried installing the activesupport gem but it still seems to fail. If anyone has any tips on how to fix this I would appreciate it thanks :)

I'm also running 64 bit Ubuntu

```
chuck@chuck-laptop:~/rails/tasks$ bundle exec guard
Guard could not detect any of the supported notification libraries.
Guard is now watching at '/home/chuck/rails/tasks'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
/home/chuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:5:in `<module:Test>': Unit is not a module (TypeError)
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-rails-2.8.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-rails-2.8.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/rails/tasks/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/rails/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/rails/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
Running all specs
/home/chuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:5:in `<module:Test>': Unit is not a module (TypeError)
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-rails-2.8.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-rails-2.8.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/rails/tasks/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/rails/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/chuck/rails/tasks/spec/requests/tasks_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `map'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:698:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /home/chuck/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
Bye bye...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WORKAROUND:

> 1. Remove **turn** gem from Gemfile.
> 2. **gem uninstall turn**

*I copypasted the workaround [from here](https://github.com/guard/guard-test/issues/10#issuecomment-1560636)*

BTW, I don't want to go too offtopic, but if you solve this issue and follow the tutorial, let me give you an advice:
If you get stuck on

```
Failure/Error: @task = Task.create :task => 'go to bed'
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       Could not find table 'tasks'
```

Then run this command:

```
rake
```

The problem is, instead of that one, they tell you to run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Which is fine, but does not migrate the test database.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As part of the tutorial you are following the narrator uses "gem 'turn' " in the gem file.  After reading some other blogs I deleted that one gem (all it does is cause pretty test output) and re-bundled.  Guard finally became functional.  I still had another error, but it would tell me how many tests passed and failed, and which were which. Hope this helps.